# how to display both key and value in object using javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I don't know if this is possible in javascript. I have a object that is dynamic.
like

```
const list = {eb: 'blue', et: 'green'}
```

anytime my list value will change like

```
const list = {er: 'yellow', ex: 'black'}
```

How can get the key value in my object? like I'm going to display both key and value for it.

```
const ikey = 'eb'
const ivalue = 'blue'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
let list = {eb: 'blue', et: 'green'}

const keyValue = (input) => Object.entries(input).forEach(([key,value]) => {
  console.log(key,value)
})


keyValue(list)
list = {er: 'yellow', ex: 'black'}
keyValue(list)
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `for..in` ,

```
for (var key in list) {
  console.log(key, list[key]);
}
```

With ES6, you can use `Object.entries`

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(list)) {
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try

for(var key in objects) {
        var value = objects[key];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Object.keys(objectNameHere)` method of the Object prototype to cycle through keys by name and enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const list = {er: 'yellow', ex: 'black'};
Object.keys(list).forEach(e=>console.log(e+"="+list[e]))
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid much computation and since V8 is great at handling JSON operations, you can simply `JSON.stringify(obj)` to give you all entries. Only problem is that you will have no control over how certain value types should be handled i.e. in that case, you will only remain with primitives as values.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get a list of key/value pairs from your object. Then you can iterate over the pairs and display them with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
Object.entries({ a: 'hello', b: 3 }).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  console.log(key, val);
});
```

You can get a list of keys with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and a list of values with [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const obj = { a: 'hello', b: 3 };

console.log(Object.keys(obj));
console.log(Object.values(obj));
console.log(Object.entries(obj));
```

Lastly, you can iterate over the object keys directly with a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, in which case you have to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to access the property on your object:

```js
const obj = { a: 'hello', b: 3 };

for (const key in obj) {
  console.log(key, obj[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [for..in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
var obj = {
  Name: 'Mohsin ',
  Age: 20,
  Address: 'Peshawar',
}

for (var keys in obj) {
  console.log(keys, ':', obj[keys])
}
```