# printing dictionary of c# with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Hi have some data to print in the client, the data is dictionary of `<string,string>`
while `userCountSpan.textContent = message;` return to the screen `object object' and not the data in the dictonary. why?

JavaScript:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        function bindConnectionMessage(connection) {
            var messageCallback = function (message) {
                console.log('message' + message);
                if (!message) return;
                var userCountSpan = document.getElementById('users');
                userCountSpan.textContent = message;
            };
            connection.on("updateCount", messageCallback);
            connection.onclose(onConnectionError);
        }
```

The value in message is the dictonary data[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as "printing" in c#. It depends what next you want to do with the data. Please clarify.

Comment: Include the response data received by your client in your question. Your server-side screenshot doesn't help at all.

Comment: @DenisWasilew I want that "message" that has the dictonary will have only the key. so the line `                userCountSpan.textContent = message;` will work

Comment: @NavahPerkal I'm not sure what it does, but suggested by the name of `userCountSpan.textContent = message; ` don't you just want to pass a count there? `Users.Count`

Comment: @DenisWasilew I want to pass `Users` which a dictionary

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to display both key and value in object using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54851645/how-to-display-both-key-and-value-in-object-using-javascript)

Comment: Unless you explain, how your output should look like, the simplest would be `userCountSpan.textContent = JSON.stringify(message)`. But I doubt, that meets your needs

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks! I used `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(message)) {
                    console.log(`${key}:`);` the result is good. but on screen when coding
                   `var thekey = `${key}`;
                    document.getElementById("users").textContent = thekey.toString();

                }` showing just 1 key. why?

Comment: Or another way? @derpirscher

Comment: @NavahPerkal another way to do what? You still haven't asked a clear question. Post what you want *in the question itself*. As for C# and dictionaries - Javascript objects *are* dictionaries. If your Javascript code receives an object from C#, perhaps in JSON form, it can already refer to its members as if it were a dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

Excused me for I don't understand much what you asked. But is this what you want:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in message)
{
      console.log("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a mix of JS and C# so I doubt, that will work ..